# Prove that a function is continuous

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $f:[0, 1] \times [0,1] \to \mathbb R$ is a function continuous in each variable and that $\{x \mapsto f(x, y): y \in [0, 1]\}$ is equicontinuous. Prove that $f$ is continuous. So fix $(x, y) \in [0, 1] \times [0, 1]$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$. We need to show that there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $|f(s, t)-f(x, y)| < \varepsilon$ whenever $(s-x)^2+(t-y)^2 < \delta^2$. But
\begin{equation*}|f(s, t)-f(x, y)| \leq |f(s, t)-f(s, y)| + |f(s, y) - f(x, y)|\end{equation*}
By equicontinuity, the second term can be made arbitrarily small. However, I'm not sure if I can use the continuity of $f$ in the second variable to make the first term arbitrarily small. In fact, I'm not even sure if I'm on the right track. Can someone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: What is $q {}{}{}{}$?

Comment: sorry. i've edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You will be better off adding and subtracting $f(x,t)$ instead of $f(s,y)$ in your triangle inequality step.  (It matters because the problem setup is not symmetric in the two variables.)

Comment: oh yes, indeed. thank you for the very helpful hint.

Comment: You're welcome.